# Extract image in Docker

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, blob

I want to download image as a blob or tar from Docker, to push somewhere as a file. Using docker-registry-client in NodeJS with method createBlobReadStream, somwhow take blob file but it is only conf file of image.

```
    async function createReadStream(DIGEST) {
    client.createBlobReadStream({ digest: DIGEST }, function (err, stream) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
            client.close();
            return
        }
        console.log('Got a digest %s', DIGEST);
        var fout = fs.createWriteStream(`//wsl$//docker-desktop-data//version-pack-data//community//docker//image//overlay2//imagedb//content//sha256//blob-${DIGEST}.file`);
        fout.on('finish', function () {
            console.log('Done downloading blob', DIGEST);
        });
        fout.on('error', function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        })
        stream.pipe(fout);
        stream.resume();
        client.close();
    })
}
```

There is addittional things I should mention:

1. All actions done in Windows 10, Docker with Linux containers
2. NodeJS as platform and docker-registry-client as library.
3. Docker data stores in ext4.vhdx

Where to extract blob or tar of just created Docker image with NodeJS?

Comment: Sorry if my question looks stupid, but since docker is installed on your machine, why don't you simply do this with the docker command directly? => `docker image pull my_image:my_tag && docker image save my_image:my_tag -o my_image-my_tag.tar`. Doing this through you above api will require much more than a single simple blob download (get manifest, parse all layers, get them individually, package the result....). Is it really worth re-implementing a full docker client you already have if saving an image content is your only requirement?

Comment: Yes, if I only wanted to download the image then your solution is correct.
But I want to write a tool to download and push to a different register. _Doing this through you above api will require much more than a single simple blob download (get manifest, parse all layers, get them individually, package the result....)._ Do you know how to do it in NodeJS?

Comment: Does it have to be a native nodejs program using that library? Could it be a compiled binary that you exec from nodejs? Do you want to support multi-platform images?

Comment: Does it have to be a native nodejs program using that library? _Yes_  Could it be a compiled binary that you exec from nodejs? _Maybe, because I can create webui in future_ Do you want to support multi-platform images? _No_

Comment: `Do you know how to do it in NodeJS?` <= no but I basically gave you the global recipe in my very first comment.

Comment: `But I want to write a tool to download and push to a different register`  Once again sorry if this looks simplistic but using what exists: `docker pull an_image:tag && docker tag an_image:tag your.registry.com/an_image:tag && docker push your.registry.com/an_image:tag`